# Passing parameter list to Umbraco API plugin controller action

Tags: c#, umbraco

How to pass a list of values to an Umbraco API plugin controller action?

I have the following action in my controller:

```
namespace web.site.Controllers 
{
    [PluginController("MyObject")]
    public class MyObjectApiController : UmbracoAuthorizedJsonController
    {
        public MyObjectApiController()
        { }

        public void Delete(List<int> ids) {
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                // ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find the right "wire format" for the ids parameter. I've tried the following:

- `ids[0]=123&ids[1]=456`;
- `ids[]=123&ids[]=456`;
- `ids=123&ids=456`.

Every time the action is called but ids is `null`. What is the right way to serialize a list of values for the action parameter?

Comment: Total shot in the dark, but what about ?ids=123,456,789 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `[FromUri]` before controller action parameter, like...

```
Delete([FromUri]List<int> ids)
```

to let model binder know to create the list of ids from parameters in the Uri.

All the formats you tried will now work when you send your request

- `ids[0]=123&ids[1]=456`
- `ids[]=123&ids[]=456`
- `ids=123&ids=456`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this requirement!